# Excel VBA Code to determine first number in column that is NOT one of specified numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of numbers in an Excel spreadsheet, which have been produced by an accelerometer and recorded by a data logger. The problem with the accelerometer is that when it is stationary it produces a lot of 'noise' values, which are always the same: 1.2753, 1.6677, 2.0601, 2.5506, 2.943, and 3.4335.

The first value in this column which is NOT one of the above numbers represents when the accelerometer begins to detect motion. Equally, the last value which is not one of the above numbers represents when the accelerometer stops detecting motion.

I have VBA code that produces an [Acceleration vs Time graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TxmS.jpg) using the above column, but it also includes all these 'noise' values. I am trying to trim these beginning and end noise values out of the column so that only motion is shown on the graph.

Is there some way of using VBA to determine the first value in the column that is NOT one of the above noise values? I'm guessing the same code can be tweaked to find the last.

I hope that I've explained this clearly. I wasn't able to find any answers to this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Help us to help you, **post your current code**.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To"). You might also want to take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour "Tour") and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. Some screenshots and sample data might also help.

Comment: @Tomi, Use `<>` this, `<>` defines does not equal, e.g. `If ActiveCell.value <> 1.2753 Then`. I cant post an answer since there is no code but this may get you on the right track. You can also use `And` to increase the amount of of items you wish to check

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for column **A**.  We make an array of "*bad*" values and then loop down the column examining each item until we find one that is not "*bad*"

```
Sub FirstGood()
    Dim v As Double, FoundIt As Boolean

    bad = Array(1.2753, 1.6677, 2.0601, 2.5506, 2.943, 3.4335)

    For i = 1 To 9999
        v = Cells(i, "A").Value
        FoundIt = True
        For j = 0 To 5
            If bad(j) = v Then FoundIt = False
        Next j
        If FoundIt Then
            MsgBox "Found valid data on row # " & i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

This is only demo code.  You must adapt it by fixing the loop limits, the column id, the response, etc.

Answer (score 0):

this is time and motion coding.

```
Sub StartWatch()
     ' store time in start column
    Dim rngTemp As Range
    Set rngTemp = ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    rngTemp = Now()

End Sub

Sub StopWatch()
     ' store time in stop column
     ' copy previous formula down
    Dim rngTemp As Range
    Set rngTemp = ActiveSheet.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    rngTemp = Now()
    rngTemp.Offset(-1, 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range(rngTemp.Offset(-1, 1), rngTemp.Offset(0, 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub StartWatch()

     ' store time in start column
    Dim rngTemp As Range
    Set rngTemp = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    rngTemp = Now()

End Sub

Sub StopWatch()
     ' store time in stop column
     ' copy previous formula down
    Dim rngTemp As Range

    Set rngTemp = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    rngTemp = Now()

    If rngTemp.Row <> 2 Then
        rngTemp.Offset(-1, 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range(rngTemp.Offset(-1, 1), rngTemp.Offset(0, 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Else
        rngTemp.Offset(, 1).Formula = "=$B2-$A2"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim PASSWORD As String 
On Error GoTo ERRORH: 
PASSWORD = InputBox("Enter Password to Close file") 
If PASSWORD = "learnmore" Then 
Else 
    Cancel = True 
End 
If ERRORH: 
    If Err.Number = 13 Then 
        Err.Clear 
    Cancel = True 
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even necessarily need to use VBA---you could have the "noise" values in a specific range of your spreadsheet, and add a `is_noise` column to your data, which uses a `VLOOKUP` or `COUNTIF` function to see if the value appears in your table of noise values. Then your chart would just exclude those values. That way, your spreadsheet would also be more flexible: If new noise values pop up, you just have to change the spreadsheet rather than updating your VBA code.